# Frequency in xts vs ts for auto.arima

Tags: r, xts

**Q:** What is the *right* way to set the frequency in an `xts` object given a set of dates? Ideally, `auto.arima()` called on this `xts` object would yield the same results as when called on an analogous `ts` object.

**Detail:** I was surprised to find different results from an `auto.arima()` fit based on whether I passed a `ts` or `xts` object. I found the difference had to do with the `frequency` (which, in the case of `xts`, was being reset to 1 despite my setting it to 12 in the construction). Below, setting up `sim_ts_12` and estimating the intended model was relatively straightforward. But in my initial attempts at working with `xts` (`sim_xts` and `sim_xts_not`) I estimated the wrong model. I finally estimated the right model using `xts` (`sim_xts_12`, `sim_ts2xts`), but both of those approaches seem *wrong* in some way. I'd expect working with `xts` to be simpler than `ts`. But that doesn't seem to be the case here. Am I missing something?

```
sim <- scan(file="./sim.dat")
sim_ts_12 <- ts(sim, start=c(2016,1), frequency=12)
sim_ts2xts_12 <- as.xts(sim_ts_12)
sim_xts <- xts(x=sim, order.by=seq.Date(from=as.Date("2016-01-01"), by="month", length.out = length(sim)))
sim_xts_12_not <- xts(x=sim, order.by=seq.Date(from=as.Date("2016-01-01"), by="month", length.out = length(sim)), frequency=12)
sim_xts_12 <- sim_xts
attr(sim_xts_12, 'frequency') <- 12

auto.arima(sim_ts_12) # ARIMA(0,1,1)(0,1,0)[12] 
auto.arima(sim_ts2xts_12) # ARIMA(0,1,1)(0,1,0)[12] 
auto.arima(sim_xts) # ARIMA(0,1,1) with drift
auto.arima(sim_xts_12_not) # ARIMA(0,1,1) with drift 
auto.arima(sim_xts_12) # ARIMA(0,1,1)(0,1,0)[12] 


txt <- "0.04767597 0.07217235 0.03954613 0.03698637 0.04283896
0.03534811 0.04198519 0.04129214 0.04576022 0.03966146
0.03656881 0.04396736 0.04459328 0.07062732 0.03477407
0.0340033 0.039136 0.0347761 0.03819997 0.03634627
0.03966617 0.03455635 0.03009606 0.03927688 0.03959629
0.06554147 0.02908742 0.02619443 0.03179742 0.02468108
0.02612955 0.02300656 0.02988827 0.01878513 0.01399028
0.02601922 0.0250159 0.05610426 0.01537538 0.01231939
0.01330564 0.008744173 0.01296571 0.005741129 0.01674992
0.003210812 -0.007936987 0.01018758"
 sim.dat <- scan(text=txt, what=numeric() )
```

**UPDATE, NOT A DUPLICATE:** The possible duplicate question/answer does not address the best practice method for handling frequency in an `xts`. The question does not ask for it, nor does the answer address it. The answer handles `ts`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the actual date plotted in X axis while plotting the auto.arima forecase in R?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40831546/how-to-get-the-actual-date-plotted-in-x-axis-while-plotting-the-auto-arima-forec)

Comment: `frequency` handling in xts is broken. If you need to use the `frequency` attribute, use `zoo` instead of `xts`. It's on my long list of things to fix...